# Joint probability of 3 random variables when their pairwise difference is given

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider 3 discrete random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ defined over $\{0..T\}$, which are identically and uniformly distributed.They are correlated in the sense that their pairwise difference has a unique given law: for instance
$$P(X_i - X_j = d) \propto e^{-|d|}\quad \mbox{for }i,j=1,2,3 \mbox{ and } i\neq j$$
Is it possible to compute the joint probability $P(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ or equivalently the conditional probability $P(X_1|X_2,X_3)$? I suspect an additional hypothesis is needed. If yes, what could be a natural assumption?

Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you find a solution for just _two_ random variables first?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: It is easy enough to find *a* solution for two random variables, but for $T \ge 2$ there may be more than one solution.

Comment: @Henry I believe the solution for two Bernoulli random variables is unique. I just wanted the OP to try something simpler first which might point to ways that the solution could be extended to three variables.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: For Bernoulli random variables $T=1$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Actually the problem is trivial for two random variables: $P(X_1,X_2) = P(X_1|X_2) P(X_2) \propto e^{-|X_1 - X_2|}$.